# SetSize and SetPosition in Selenium VBA

Tags: vba, excel, google-chrome, selenium

I've been trying to use Selenium in my VBA to set a new position and size to the chrome to make it "inviseble" while I'm updating my reports.

```
    bot.Start "chrome"
    bot.Window.SetPosition ("X as Long, Y as long")  'It requires a "="        
    bot.Window.Setsize(200,200) 'It requires a "="
```

I've tried different forms and googled a lot, but I didn't find a good tutorial for Selenium' VBA commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got what i wanted

```
        bot.Start "chrome", weburl
        iEsq = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)
        bot.Window.SetPosition iEsq - 1, 0
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there's probably an error in the definition of the function, but you can use this alternate function call notation and it will work:

```
bot.Window.SetSize 200, 200
```

Not my solution...I had the same problem.  Found the solution here:
https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/issues/58

You could also submit a bug there if you think it's worthwhile to get it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the brackets like this:

```
bot.Window.SetPosition X, Y
bot.Window.Setsize 200, 200
```